# Range not selecting correctly

Tags: excel, vba, filter, range

Could someone please point out the error in my range definition `.Range("B1:D" & lRow2).Copy` - I have tried multiple variations of the range definition, but they all either copy only the header row or copy lots of blank rows. Could this be due to wrong interaction with the filtering?

```
Sub PillarInstances_WordDoc_FormatTbl()

    Dim PlDict As Object
    Dim Pl As Range
    Dim PlLst As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lRow2 As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim HoldingPath As String
    Dim LastDay As Date
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim WordDocName As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    HoldingPath = "C:\Users\abc\xyz\Instances\"
    LastDay = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0) 'last day of previous month
    lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lRow2 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
    Set ws = Worksheets("Instances")

        ws.Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Instances").Unlist
    
    Set PlDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
    
    With PlDict
        For Each Pl In ws.Range("A2:A" & lRow)
            If Not .Exists(Pl.Text) Then .Add Pl.Text, Nothing
        Next Pl
        PlLst = .Keys
    End With
    
    With ws.Range("A1")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">" & CLng(LastDay) 
        For i = 0 To PlDict.Count - 1
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria2:=PlLst(i)
            .Range("B1:D" & lRow2).Copy
        
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add("C:\Users\abc\xyz\ReportTemplate1.dotx")
        wdDoc.Bookmarks("InstancesTable").Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
        WordDocName = PlLst(i) & "_Instances_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
        wdDoc.SaveAs Filename:=HoldingPath & WordDocName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument

        wdDoc.Close savechanges:=False
        Set wdDoc = Nothing
        
        Next i
    End With
    
    ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    ws.Name = "Instances_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `.Range("B1:D" & lRow2).Copy` points to that `With` block `With ws.Range("A1")` so it gets `ws.Range("A1").Range("B1:D" & lRow2).Copy` but it should be `ws.Range("B1:D" & lRow2).Copy` and in `lRow2 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` you did not specify in which worksheet you are looking for the last row. Never use `Range` or `Cells` without specifying a worksheet (or Excel will guess and might fail).

Comment: Thanks @PEH - understood! But am struggling now with the next step, because the column for filtering (col F) is outside `.Range("B1:D" & lRow2)`. What should I replace `ws.Range("A1")` with? I have tried with `ws.CurrentRegion` but that gives an error.

Comment: leave `ws.Range("A1")` but specify the worksheet like `ws.Range("B1:D" & lRow2).Copy` for the copy line. I can just guess as we don't know how your data looks like before and after applying the filter.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following adjustment to solve the filter problem:

1)You have write `.AutoFilter` twice, which is not necessay

2)When you try to create a filter, it will be better to determine the range from 1st row until last row in VBA

3)Write `xlCellTypeVisible` to prevent copy blank row

```
   With ws.Range("A1&F" & lRow2)
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">" & CLng(LastDay)
            For i = 0 To PlDict.Count - 1
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria2:=PlLst(i)
                .Range("B1:D" & lRow2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

4)After all the action is done, it is advised to reset the filter to display all information:

```
With ws.Range("A1&F" & lRow2)
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria2:="="
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Kin, I am still only getting the header row, also when I add `ws` as recommnded by @PEH i.e. `ws.Range("B1:D" & lRow2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`

Comment: I see, maybe you should start from `B2` instead of `B1`, because you should not copy the header. If you need the header also, make it separate part by just copy `B1:D1`

Comment: The problem is in the filtering, not the copying. Please excuse a poorly analyzed problem. :-(

Comment: ok, you can try use macro recorder and record your action, from there you will know what is the correct filter criteria you should use, especially you are using `>`. Until today I will still use the recorder in case I not 100% confirm.

Comment: Many thanks Kin and @PEH - your tips have been very helpful!